# Removing a character from my stringbuilder

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am having the following string builder as msrtResult, which is quite long:

```
mstrResult.Append(rtbResult.Text).Append("})})" + Environment.NewLine)
```

How can I remove the last "," from mstrResult Now? (it is in the middle of that mstrResult and it is not the last character of the whole string since I am appending strings to it)
I should do it before adding the newline. 
Thanks

Comment: I, too, don't fully understand your question/goal. Where is that comma put into the StringBuilder? If it is contained in the `rtbResult.Text` you may consider replacing it there.

Answer (score 68):

You can just decrease the length to shorten the string (C#):

```
mstrResult.Length -= 1;
```

EDIT:

After you updated you question, I think I know what you want :) How about this:

```
mstrResult.Append(rtbResult.Text).Append("})})" + Environment.NewLine);
var index = mstrResult.ToString().LastIndexOf(',');
if (index >= 0)
    mstrResult.Remove(index, 1);
```

Comment: +1 I didn't think it would let you do this, but checked MSDN and yep it looks good.  I like.

Comment: One thing to watch for is that you have added a command in the first place and that this code doesn't either fail due to the string not having any commas, or fails by removing a comma from an earlier portion of the text.

Comment: @David You're right. Added a check to verify that there's really a comma present. I wasn't sure if @Faulty wanted to remove the comma from rtbResult of mstrResult, but changing that would be trivial.

Comment: mstrResult.Length -= 1; This works for me. cheers

Comment: The solution for C# should be through stringbuilder. Anything solution that doesn't mention stringbuilder is wrong IMHO. Yes, you can do it many other ways, but we should teach stringbuilder as the basics considering the exponential costs to not using it.

Answer (score 16):

Add a StringBuilder extension.

```
public static StringBuilder RemoveLast(this StringBuilder sb, string value)
{
    if(sb.Length < 1) return sb;
    sb.Remove(sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(value), value.Length);
    return sb;
}
```

then invoke:

```
yourStringBuilder.RemoveLast(",");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`StringBuilder.Remove()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.remove.aspx) if you know the position of the character(s) you want to remove.

I'd imagine that it would be easier not to add it in the first place.

---

Your updated question talks about removing the last comma character. I'm guessing you want to do this to avoid creating a message that looks like this:

> My shopping list contained milk, eggs,
>   butter, and fish.

You'd assemble this in a loop, iterating over an array.  Usually you can write the loop so that you simply choose (e.g. with an if statement) not to add the command when you are in the final iteration of the loop.

Comment: I do not know the position unfortuantely and also i can not do that because i am in an iteration and I just need to remove the last character of ","

Comment: If you added the , at the start rather than at the end, you would know that it was the first one that need removing ... and then could you use Remove ?

Comment: Long live the Oxford comma!

Answer (score 2):

To just remove the last character you appended use below: (This is VB but C should work similarly)

```
Dim c As New StringBuilder
c.Remove(c.Length - 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
mstrResult.Remove( mstrResult.Length - 1 - Environment.NewLine.Length
                 , Environment.NewLine.Length);
```

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
stringbuilder blahh = new stringbuilder()
int searchKey = blahh.LastIndexOf(',');
```

then call

```
blahh.Remove( searchKey, 1).Insert(searchKey, " and"); or a blank.
```