# Best way to remove the last character from a string built with stringbuilder

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I have the following

```
data.AppendFormat("{0},",dataToAppend);
```

The problem with this is that I am using it in a loop and there will be a trailing comma. What is the best way to remove the trailing comma?

Do I have to change data to a string and then substring it?

Comment: `string.Join(",", yourCollection)`? Edit: added as answer.

Comment: did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701163/removing-a-character-from-my-stringbuilder?

Comment: @Chris: this way you don't need a StringBuilder at all.

Comment: maybe you can avoid adding the comma instead of removing it afterwards. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581448/join-a-string-using-delimiters (Jon Skeet's answer)

Comment: @Vlad Yeah sorry, I misread that; I thought you were offering it as a suggestion to alter the final-built string, not as a replacement for his loop altogether. (I thought I deleted my comment in time, guess not!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799446/creating-a-comma-separated-list-from-iliststring-or-ienumerablestring

Comment: You should probably retitle the question since it's not what's needed for the solution. But as posted in the duplicates the easiest way to take characters off the end of a StringBuilder is to reduce its length.

Comment: The 'duplicate' question is not really (at least not any more). This asks for the last character; the other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5701163/292060 asks for the last of a certain character (comma), which may not be the last in the string.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

The simplest and **most efficient way** is to perform this command:

```
data.Length--;
```

by doing this you move the pointer (i.e. last index) back one character but you don't change the mutability of the object. In fact, clearing a `StringBuilder` is best done with `Length` as well (but do actually use the `Clear()` method for clarity instead because that's what its implementation looks like):

```
data.Length = 0;
```

again, because it doesn't change the allocation table. Think of it like saying, I don't want to recognize these bytes anymore. Now, even when calling `ToString()`, it won't recognize anything past its `Length`, well, it can't. It's a mutable object that allocates more space than what you provide it, it's simply built this way.

Comment: re `data.Length = 0;`: that's exactly what `StringBuilder.Clear` does, so it's preferable to use `StringBuilder.Clear` for clarity of intention.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez, fair enough friend, I should have more clearly stated that's what `Clear()` does, but funny thing. That's the **first line** of the `Clear()` method. But, did you know the interface actually then issues a `return this;`. Now that's the thing that kills me. Setting the `Length = 0` changes the reference you already have, why return yourself?

Comment: I think it's for being able to use in a "fluent" manner. `Append` returns itself as well.

Answer (score 54):

Just use

```
string.Join(",", yourCollection)
```

This way you don't need the `StringBuilder` and the loop.

---

---

---

*Long addition about async case.* As of 2019, it's not a rare setup when the data are coming asynchronously.

In case your data are in async collection, there is no `string.Join` overload taking `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. But it's easy to create one manually, hacking [the code from `string.Join`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/String.Manipulation.cs,f31a26ccc99600e8):

```
public static class StringEx
{
    public static async Task<string> JoinAsync<T>(string separator, IAsyncEnumerable<T> seq)
    {
        if (seq == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(seq));

        await using (var en = seq.GetAsyncEnumerator())
        {
            if (!await en.MoveNextAsync())
                return string.Empty;

            string firstString = en.Current?.ToString();

            if (!await en.MoveNextAsync())
                return firstString ?? string.Empty;

            // Null separator and values are handled by the StringBuilder
            var sb = new StringBuilder(256);
            sb.Append(firstString);

            do
            {
                var currentValue = en.Current;
                sb.Append(separator);
                if (currentValue != null)
                    sb.Append(currentValue);
            }
            while (await en.MoveNextAsync());
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

---

If the data are coming asynchronously but the interface `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` is not supported (like the mentioned in comments `SqlDataReader`), it's relatively easy to wrap the data into an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`:

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<(object first, object second, object product)> ExtractData(
        SqlDataReader reader)
{
    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        yield return (reader[0], reader[1], reader[2]);
}
```

and use it:

```
Task<string> Stringify(SqlDataReader reader) =>
    StringEx.JoinAsync(
        ", ",
        ExtractData(reader).Select(x => $"{x.first} * {x.second} = {x.product}"));
```

In order to use `Select`, you'll need to use nuget package [`System.Interactive.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/). [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VubceD) you can find a compilable example.

Answer (score 15):

How about this..

```
string str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog,";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the following after the loop.

```
.TrimEnd(',')
```

or simply change to

```
string commaSeparatedList = input.Aggregate((a, x) => a + ", " + x)
```

Comment: He is using StringBuilder not string. Moreover it is quite ineffective: first conversion to string then trimming.

Comment: or `string.Join(",", input)`

Answer (score 11):

I prefer manipulating the length of the stringbuilder:

```
data.Length = data.Length - 1;
```

Comment: Why not simply `data.Length--` or `--data.Length`?

Comment: I usually use data.Length-- but in one case I had to move back 2 characters because of a blank value after the character I wanted to remove. Trim did not work in that case either  so data.Length = data.Length - 2; worked.

Comment: Trim returns a new instance of a string, it does not alter the contents of the stringbuilder object

Comment: @GoneCoding Visual Basic .NET doesn't support `--` or `++`  You can use `data.Length -= 1` though, or this answer will work too.

Answer (score 4):

## Gotcha!!

Most of the answers on this thread won't work if you use `AppendLine` like below:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("One,");
builder.Length--; // Won't work
Console.Write(builder.ToString());

builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("One,");
builder.Length += -1; // Won't work
Console.Write(builder.ToString());

builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("One,");
Console.Write(builder.TrimEnd(',')); // Won't work
```

[Fiddle Me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HNWTX1)

**WHY???** @*(&**(&@*!!

The issue is simple but took me a while to figure it out: Because there are 2 more **invisible** characters at the end `CR` and `LF` (Carriage Return and Line Feed). Therefore, you need to take away 3 last characters:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("One,");
builder.Length -= 3; // This will work
Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
```

**In Conclusion**

Use `Length--` or `Length -= 1` if the last method you called was `Append`. Use `Length =- 3` if you the last method you called `AppendLine`.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend, you change your loop algorithm:

- Add the comma not AFTER the item, but BEFORE
- Use a boolean variable, that starts with false, do suppress the first comma
- Set this boolean variable to true after testing it

Comment: This is probably the least efficient of all suggestions (and requires more code).

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `string.Join` method to turn a collection of items into a comma delimited string.  It will ensure that there is no leading or trailing comma, as well as ensure the string is constructed efficiently (without unnecessary intermediate strings).

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way would be to use the Join() method:

```
public static void Trail()
{
    var list = new List<string> { "lala", "lulu", "lele" };
    var data = string.Join(",", list);
}
```

If you really need the StringBuilder, trim the end comma after the loop:

```
data.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: `data.ToString().TrimEnd(',');` is inefficient

Comment: Also, you may not want to convert the StringBuilder object to String as it may have multiple lines ending with ","

Answer (score 2):

Yes, convert it to a string once the loop is done:

```
String str = data.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: it is quite ineffective: first conversion to string then trimming.

Comment: @Garath If you meant "inefficient", I wouldn't disagree. But it _would_ be effective.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. First one is very easy use `Remove` method it is quite effective. Second way is to use `ToString` with start index and end index ([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyx7s61s.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

[Similar SO question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701163/removing-a-character-from-my-stringbuilder)

I liked the using a StringBuilder extension method.

[RemoveLast Method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9087575/2336008)

Answer (score 0):

Simply shortens the stringbuilder length by 1;

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Length--;
```

i know this is not the effective way as it translates to `sb = sb-1;`

**Alternative Effective solution**

```
sb.Remove(starting_index, how_many_character_to_delete);
```

for our case it would be

```
sb.Remove(sb.length-1,1)
```